dash app behavior has suddenly changed from reading a ".cfg" to trying to download it
I have been running a dash app in which I've kept files to be read under the assets directory. But now all of a sudden, when I select a *.cfg file (specifically, this one) I'm prompted to download it instead of it just being read (which is the preferred behavior). I have ".txt" files in another assets subdirectory and those simply get read as usual without any attempt to download. Maybe there's a mime type setting or something else going on in my app that's causing this? I'm really puzzled about why this problem has appeared all of a sudden.
I moved this file to other assets subfolders and even created a separate static folder to hold the .cfg file. All of these efforts had the same result of my Windows PC trying to save the file instead of just read it.
I hope this is enough information to work with. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.
TJ
Edit: I found a solution. I added the following lines to my app.py file and this did the trick!
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/plain", ".cfg", True)

